# Spyder 5 won't launch

Tags: anaconda, spyder, launch

I just downloaded Spyder 5 using

```
conda upgrade anaconda
conda install spyder=5.0.0
```

However, after installation when I launch Spyder from the Windows menu, I see a pop up indicating that Spyder 5 is launching. However, after a few seconds the popup disappears and Spyder does not launch.

When I try to launch Spyder from the Anaconda Navigator, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\kite\kite_completions.png is overriding the existing kite_completions
f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\old_svg\CloseButton.svg is overriding the existing CloseButton
f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\spyder2_icon_theme\folding.arrow_down_off.png is overriding the existing folding.arrow_down_off
f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\spyder2_icon_theme\folding.arrow_down_on.png is overriding the existing folding.arrow_down_on
f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\spyder2_icon_theme\folding.arrow_right_off.png is overriding the existing folding.arrow_right_off
f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\spyder2_icon_theme\folding.arrow_right_on.png is overriding the existing folding.arrow_right_on
f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\image_path_manager.py:46: UserWarning: The icon located in C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\images\tour\tour-spyder-logo.svg is overriding the existing tour-spyder-logo
f'The icon located in {complete_path} is overriding '
No QCoreApplication instance found. Application patches not applied. You have to call load_stylesheet function after instantiation of QApplication to take effect. 
ipython_console: cannot import name 'secure_write' from 'jupyter_core.paths' (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\solver.py", line 117, in find_external_plugins
mod = importlib.import_module(entry_point.module_name)
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "", line 728, in exec_module
File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\plugins\ipythonconsole\plugin.py", line 24, in 
from jupyter_client.connect import find_connection_file
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 4, in 
from .connect import *
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 35, in 
from jupyter_core.paths import jupyter_data_dir, jupyter_runtime_dir, secure_write
ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_write' from 'jupyter_core.paths' (C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_core\paths.py)
Pruned plugin: variable_explorer
Pruned plugin: plots
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2146, in create_window
main.setup()
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 836, in setup
plugin_deps = solve_plugin_dependencies(enabled_plugins.values())
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\solver.py", line 210, in solve_plugin_dependencies
plugin_deps = [plugin_names[name] for name in deps]
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\solver.py", line 210, in 
plugin_deps = [plugin_names[name] for name in deps]
KeyError: 'plots'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 214, in main
mainwindow.main(options, args)
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2293, in main
mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 2148, in create_window
if main.console is not None:
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 1159, in __getattr__
return self.get_plugin(self._INTERNAL_PLUGINS_MAPPING[attr])
File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\mainwindow.py", line 168, in get_plugin
raise SpyderAPIError('Plugin "{}" not found!'.format(plugin_name))
spyder.api.exceptions.SpyderAPIError: Plugin "internal_console" not found!
```

I have already tried the following things already (unsuccessfully):

- Uninstalling (through Windows menu) Spyder and reinstalling it in the Anaconda prompt
- Installing Spyder 4 again `conda install spyder=4.0.0`. However, this does not launch either anymore.

What can I do to launch Spyder again?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This part of your error `ImportError: cannot import name 'secure_write' from 'jupyter_core.paths'` indicates that you have a serious installation problem in Anaconda. So my recommendation is to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda again. And to do that, please follow the instructions in [our video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ul79ihg41Rs) about it.

Comment: If you want to use Spyder without any issues and avoid all the headaches involved after every update in Anaconda, another option is to use our [Windows installer](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases/download/v5.0.0/Spyder_64bit_full.exe).

Comment: @CarlosCordoba That's the recommended way to install it now?  It should say that in the upgrade popup then (instead of `conda install spyder=5.0.0` which breaks everything)?

Comment: Using our Windows and macOS installers is now the recommended way to install Spyder. We mention that in our [docs](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/installation.html#standalone-installers), [webpage](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) and [Github releases page](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/releases).

Comment: However, if you installed Spyder with Anaconda, then we have to tell people how to update it using `conda` (I think it'd be quite confusing to recommend a different method). Unfortunately, we don't have any control over how `conda` performs updates, and that's why we created our installers. Usually it's a good strategy to use a different environment instead of your base one to try new versions, and wait a couple of months before installing a new major version (not only of Spyder, but of any software in general).

Answer (score 4):

Try to use:

`icon_theme = spyder 2`

in the file C:\Users<user_name>.spyder-py3\config\spyder.ini

Comment: This is a solution that doesn't need admin rights. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You need remove Spyder History.

```
rm ~/.config/spyder-py3
```

Comment: Thank this worked for me. Had to add the -r though (it's a folder not a file).
rm -r ~/.config/spyder-py3

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I just completely uninstalled anaconda 3 with the Uninstall-Anaconda.exe then I reinstalled and updated everything again. That may not really be a viable option for you but I did get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Below commands worked for me without breaking anything:

```
conda update anaconda
```

and then

```
conda install spyder=5
```